# PHP Date Formats (6 Decimal point seconds)

Tags: php

I'm working with a piece of software that stores time in the following format:

```
2015-07-31 23:00:00.000000
```

I need to be able to add a length such as

```
00:00:00.190952
```

to the above date. Where on earth do I start with this? No combination of adding and date/time additions seem to play ball :(

Comment: `date('u')`  gives you microseconds, but any dates GENERATED by php (e.g. `date`, `DateTime` objects) will only be accurate to full seconds.

Comment: From the [manua](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)l: __Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds if DateTime was created with microseconds.__ So it sounds like it might be possible. If you end up having to convert to floats and doing the math yourself, make sure you use something like the BCMath library, because the default float type won't keep precision correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can combinate `microtime()` and `date()`:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", substr($m = microtime(),11)) . substr($m,1,7);
```